# Is Camel Spring ws compatible with spring ws 2.0.2.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-ws, apache-camel

The [documentation says](http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html) that camel-spring-ws(v2.7.1) officially supports spring-ws 1.5.9, but doesn't mention spring-ws 2.0.2.RELEASE.  I'd like to stick with 2.0.2.RELEASE instead trying to [retrofit 1.5.9 to work with Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313314/can-spring-ws-1-5-be-used-with-spring-3), but I'm hitting enough roadblocks to make me think that it's just not going to work.

Has anyone been successful with this?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ticket to upgrade to use Spring 2.0.2. The was a bug in Spring WS 2.0.0 and 2.0.1 releases in terms of not working with OSGi. That should hopefully be fixed in Spring WS 2.0.2.

If you are not using OSGi you can most likely manually upgrade to Spring WS 2.0.x. But it requires a bit of work as some JARs have changed and whatnot.

Camel 2.8 should use the Spring WS 2.0.2 by default.

The ticket is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3735

Comment: Quick followup - switched to Camel 2.8 and Spring WS 2.0.2 is handled beautifully.