# XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException --> cannot find tag

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, portlet, spring-ws

When trying to deploy my portlet, wich uses a webservice, i get this exception thrown at me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
```

I've searched google, and didnt find a solution..

My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd" >

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.icredit.einvoice.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest" />

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService"/>
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
         <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
         <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://localhost:8081/ws-demo/account-balance-service" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I know there is something wrong with the oxm:jaxb2-marshaller tag... But what? I followed instructions as listed in some tutorials.

It looks like the compiler does'nt find the declaration oxm:jaxb2 marshaller, but it is defined above.

Below you can find my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.icredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>einvoice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>einvoice Portlet</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.6</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
        <spring.suite.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.suite.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>BatchDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.BatchDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>BatchDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerAccountDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerAccountDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerAccountDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailStatusDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailStatusDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailStatusDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>FileService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.FileService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>FileService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SenderDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.SenderDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>SenderDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <classifier>all</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Spring version you're using

```
<spring.suite.version>3.2.10</spring.suite.version>
```

And look at your schema location version

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd
```

You're using 4.1. Your spring version 3.2.10 won't have the xsd for 4.1, only 3.2 and below. You can just exclude the version

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
```

And Spring will find the latest xsd version for you in the the `spring-oxm` jar, which is [where you will find the `jaxb2-marshaller` element](http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd) .

---

### Actually

On top of that, I ran your pom (at least just the with the Spring dependencies), and none of those dependencies you declared had a `spring-oxm` transitive dependency, and you have not explicitly declared `spring-oxm`. So you will need to do that also.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### UPDATE

Based on [Can Spring-WS 1.5 be used with Spring 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313314/can-spring-ws-1-5-be-used-with-spring-3) and the answers given, its looks like `spring-ws` 1.5 is not compatible with Spring 3. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063730/2587435) provides a work around

Comment: I thought the explicite oxm dependency wasnt needed because i used spring-ws-all. Now i'm getting further.. But when use contextPath, my compiler complains that i cant use it. If I use context-path, my IDE complains that I cant use it..

Comment: Never used `spring-ws` but when I built your pom, it didn't bring in the required `spring-oxm`

Comment: Ok I see. I'm looking at the jar. I do see the xsd in the `org.springframework.oxm.config` package, but its `1.5`. Try leaving out the version. And take out the `spring-oxm` dependency. Another thing you might want to consider is the compatibility of the `spring-ws` and the default spring version you're us ing. I know spring has a lot of version dependency issue. You might want to try one of the higher versions. Note in the 2.x.x versions, the oxm package is not there, so if you do this then you need to declare the spring-oxm. Again, sorry like I said, I've never used spring-ws

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2011/01/11/spring-web-services-2-0-released). It may help

Comment: Also see [Can Spring-WS 1.5 be used with Spring 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3313314/2587435). I think that more directly looks at your situation about version compatibility

Comment: solved. So I use the latest spring-core and spring-oxm (and not the all in one package).

Comment: You may also want to dig into Spring Boot. It will manage all your dependency versions for you, and for the most part you won't run into version conflicts

Comment: My collegue/senior said that I should stay away from Spring Boot at the moment.. But now my issues are solved. Thanks for the effort all!

Answer (score 0):

In your xml where is the schema location provided for

```
      xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd"
```

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd is not available anymore. :(

Comment: you edited your question, at first you dont write the schema location for xmlns:oxm.